# How to stop querying when it reaches a specific class with XPath?

Tags: dom, xpath

Say I have the following:

```
<div class="data">
    <h2 class="entry-contentH2">Preparation</h2>
    <h2>Airplanes</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>3 large</strong> wings</li>
        <li><strong>2</strong>doors</li>
    </ul>
    <h2>Car</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><strong>4</strong> doors</li>
        <li><strong>1 cup</strong> holder</li>
    </ul>
    <h2 class="stopHeader">Execution</h2>
    <h2>Motorcycles</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>Easy to learn</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get query all of the `<p></p>` tags text after the `<h2>Preparing</h2>`, but I want it to stop at the last `<p></p>` before the stopHeader class.

This is the code that I came up with:

```
//h2[contains(.,"Preparation")]/following-sibling::h2/text()[not(preceding::h2[@class="stopHeader"])]

#and also
//h2[contains(.,"Preparation")]/following-sibling::h2/text()[not(preceding::h2[contains(., "Execution")])]
```

Comment: This seem to work. Did you get wrong output?

Comment: For some reason it's querying all the p tags, including the ones after the stopHeader.

Comment: What if to replace `[@class="stopHeader"]` with `[@class="stopheader"]`? XPath is case-sensitive

Comment: Nothing so far.

Comment: What is your desired output? `"Airplanes"`, `"Car"`?

Comment: Yes, get all h2 before "Execution"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below XPath to get desired output:

```
//h2[.="Preparation"]/following-sibling::h2[./following-sibling::h2[.="Execution"]]/text()
```

This should return text content of each header (`h2`) between `"Preparation"` and `"Execution"`

Comment: Thanks Andersson, it works but I'm going to understand what happened here because nothing I had tried worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath.

```
//h2[text()='Preparation']/following::h2[not(@class='stopHeader')]/text()
```

Comment: Hello, Have you try this answer? Provide your feedback.